# Need advice on my quadratic formula functions

Tags: visual-c++

Okay The program compiles, but i am getting wrong output. Any help would be awesome. i do understand there are many other examples on this topic and i have looked at them all. None seemed to have help me clearly understand.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double quadplus(float a, float b, float c);
double quadminus(float a, float b, float c);

int main()
{  
  double a, b, c;
  double discriminant;

  cout << "Please Enter variables for a, b, and c." << endl << endl;
  cout << "Enter number for variable a." << endl << endl;
  cin >> a;
  cout << "Enter number for variable b." << endl << endl;
  cin >> b;
  cout << "Enter number for variable c." << endl << endl;
  cin >> c;
  discriminant = (b * b) - (4 * a * c); 

  if(discriminant == 0)
      cout << quadplus(a,b,c) << endl;
  else if(discriminant > 0)
      cout << quadplus(a,b,c) << endl;
  else if(discriminant < 0)
      cout << quadminus(a,b,c) << quadplus(a,b,c) << endl;

  return 0;
}

double quadplus(float a, float b, float c)
    {
        return ((-1 * b) + (sqrt(( b * b) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a));
    }
double quadminus(float a, float b, float c)
     {
        return ((-1 * b) - (sqrt(( b * b) - (4 * a * c))) / ( 2 * a));
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << quadplus << endl;
```

should probably be

```
cout << quadplus(a, b, c) << endl;
```

Also, if the discriminant is negative, your solutions will be
complex numbers of the form `x + yi` and your code doesn't properly account
for that.  If `discriminant != 0`,  you should probably print both roots.

Comment: Im not sure what i would change if there where complex numbers.

Comment: In that case, you could take the square root of the absolute value of the discriminant (so, positive and real), then calculate x = -b/2a,  y = sqrt(abs(discriminant))/2a, and report the complex roots as x - yi and x + yi.